# WordPress Как перенести медиафайлы в новый WP?

Tags: wordpress

Имееться два сайта на `WordPress`. Один старый, с которого необходимо забрать все медиафайлы (изображение/документы) и перенести на новый, где уже имеються свои посты и медиафайлы.
Мои действия.

1. Забрал со старого сайта всю категорию `uploads` и залил в новий сайт.
2. Экспортировал все значения из таблицы `wp_posts` у которых `post_type=attachment`
   Дальше заменил значения на свои и заимпортировал в собственную базу данных нового сайта.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `wp_posts` (`ID`, `post_author`, `post_date`, `post_date_gmt`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`, `comment_status`, `ping_status`, `post_password`, `post_name`, `to_ping`, `pinged`, `post_modified`, `post_modified_gmt`, `post_content_filtered`, `post_parent`, `guid`, `menu_order`, `post_type`, `post_mime_type`, `comment_count`) VALUES
(768, 1, '2019-10-07 14:13:58', '2019-10-07 14:13:58', '', 'Refugee Integration & Economic Contributions', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'refugee-integration-economic-contributions', '', '', '2019-10-07 14:13:58', '2019-10-07 14:13:58', '', 767, 'https://rcusa.websitetesturl2.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Refugee-Integration-Economic-Contributions.pdf', 0, 'attachment', 'application/pdf', 0),
(770, 1, '2019-10-07 14:18:29', '2019-10-07 14:18:29', '', 'At A Glance - Refugee Integration and Economic Contributions', '', 'inherit', 'closed', 'closed', '', 'at-a-glance-refugee-integration-and-economic-contributions', '', '', '2019-10-07 14:18:29', '2019-10-07 14:18:29', '', 769, 'https://rcusa.websitetesturl2.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/At-A-Glance-Refugee-Integration-and-Economic-Contributions.pdf', 0, 'attachment', 'application/pdf', 0);
```

Оно нормально заимпортировало, где надо сменило ID  в нужной таблице... Но в новом сайте я все ещё не наблюдаю их в `Media Library` почему ? Что я делаю, не так, почему они не отображаються в библиотеке и их нельзя выбрать или назначить другому посту ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тупанул... импортировал значения таблици не в ту базу данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Что я делаю, не так

Всего-то и нужно было, что сделать импорт.

- Если только медиафайлов, то достаточно и стандартного.
  Или второй вариант - залив вручную на сервер использовать плагины для регистрации в медиатеке. Например [media sync](https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/)
- Если же с привязкой к существующим записям, то уже плагины импорта.

*А своими действиями ты с большой долей вероятности поломал базу.*

Comment: Спасибо, мой метод рабочий, но только если файлов меньше сотни. Воспользовался предложеним media sync ... Там тоже с первого раза не вишло, базавая версия только до 400 файлов нормально в базу записывает.

Comment: @BlackStar1991 если что есть и другие плагины для этого. Я в своё время в репо как минимум шт 5 видел-пробовал. И файлов регил несколько тыщ (переделывал ИМ с +7летней историей).